# Calling qdecimal Library function

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use the [qdecimal library](https://code.google.com/p/qdecimal/) and I am unable to call any of the exposed methods. I have successfully built the library file (libdecnumber.a) and added it and its include files to my project's .pro file and included the associated headers as outlined in [example 1](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.pdf) in the readme docs. I can use the #defines and other types from the library, but I will always get an "undefined reference to" for any function calls.

For example,

```
//these compile
#include "decNumber.h" // base number library 
decNumber a, b; // working numbers
decContext set; // working context

//this does not
decNumberFromString(&b, "test", &set);
```

Is this indicative of the library not being added to the project correctly or is it something else?

Comment: It seems you're not linking your project to the library. What environment are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QtCreator, open .pro file in it and add line

```
LIBS += -ldecnumber
```

You can specify path if needed with -L"...path here..."

Currently you haven't linked your project with the library.

Comment: Unfortunately I have done that with the correct path. I still get the undefined reference errors though

Comment: Could you please post more details about what compiler are using and your application is 32-bit or 64-bit? It seems that library was built with different settings than you are using.

Comment: yes, you are correct. It looks like the library that shipped with the plugin was built using a different compiler than mine. I recompiled the library with my compiler and all is well now